# Extending data context classes (interface, new properties etc)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How could I extend my data context objects (generated by Linq To Sql) so I can attach another interface to them, add other properties etc.? I don't want this to get overwritten the next time I'm rebuilding the classes from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what partial classes are for.  Just add your stuff in a new cs file with the class of the same name declared partial.